# GDB No such file or directory with set dir

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, c99

I compile my code with gcc -g, I set my dir with `dir "path to my code files"` but stil no of my working code runs in gdb, when I'm using step.

Just using malloc and execvp

Example:

```
(gdb) s
__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=16) at malloc.c:3028
3028    **malloc.c: No such file or directory.**
```

or

```
 (gdb) s
__GI_execvp (file=0x555555756040 <input> "spam", argv=0x555555757a80) at execvp.c:26
26      **execvp.c: No such file or directory.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it works, it's just that you don't have the source for those system functions. you're stepping into _system functions_ not your code.